# How to create email address in format of "me+foo@provider.com"?

Tags: gmail

I was looking on a person's resume and he has put his email like this: `foo+resume@gmail.com`.

I am talking about that additional `+resume`. I want to know:

1. How this type of email address works?
2. How do I create email like that with my present Gmail address?

I tried creating an email address with `+` in between, but Gmail only allows letters, numbers and periods.

Comment: Could it be that he/she wanted to prevent bots from detecting it as an e-mail? As in mefoo (at) provider.com.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Send an email at `team+webapps@stackexchange.com` and you'll receive a reply.

Comment: This wiki says it's possible: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses. I guess it's a Gmail policy. I just tried to create a test+test@gmail.com, but it showed an error

Comment: This make a great way to filter and label incoming email. Any email with that +keyword must have found my email on that job search site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything after the + sign in the email prefix is generally ignored by mail servers and resolves and sends to the address without the [+word].  It's a way to easily track who sends you email.

In your example, foo@gmail.com would receive the email, and "+resume" would be ignored, but the recipient (foo@gmail.com) will receive an email with foo+resume@gmail.com in the recipient (TO) list.

See Gmail reference: [Using an address alias](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=12096)

Comment: You can't create an account as such. It must be an alias.

Comment: @MacGyver Got it.

Comment: It works with virtually all email addresses/providers as well, not only Gmail

Comment: @SantoshKumar You should probably also know that while this is part of the email standard and a great technique, you'll still receive an "invalid email" in a fair amount of web applications.